# TYPO3 bootstrap_core changes paths to includes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, path, typo3

I have installed the bootstrap_core extension just a minute ago and am having problems with my TypoScript includes.

In my TypoScript i am writing the following:

```
includeJS.jQuery = http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
includeJS.bs = fileadmin/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js
includeJS.mainJS = fileadmin/js/main.js
includeCSS.bootstrap= fileadmin/bs/css/bootstrap.min.css
includeCSS.fontAwesome = fileadmin/font-awesome-4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css
includeCSS.mainCSS = fileadmin/css/main.css
```

This works nice without the bootstrap_core extension active.
However, if the exension is active, there is made a / before the path on the page:

```
<img id="logo" class="img-responsive centered" src="/fileadmin/images/personenbetreuung-christina-watzinger.svg">
```

This causes the page to be faulty, because the paths can't be translated properly.

Someone knows how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking the ext I am pretty sure it sets one of the following properties:

```
config {
  absRefPrefix = 
  baseURL = 
}
```

Using `/` should only break your TYPO3 installation if it is installed in a subdirectory. Best would be therefore to set the `absRefPrefix` to `/subfolder/`.

Comment: hey, thank you for the fast reply.
Do you mean that i have to add your code above into my TypoScript?

My fileadmin structure is like:
-fileadmin
---css
-----main.css
---js
-----main.js
---bootstrap
and so on.

Comment: Yes, add it to the TypoScript using the module "Template" on your root page  into the section "setup"

Comment: can you please mark the answer as solution then? thanks!